# In Xamarin.Forms how to set a popup page in desired position using RG.Plugin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

I installed the Nuget package Rg.plugins.popup. 
Tried to set a popup page that should appear on right. 
Tried different ways but not able find a solution

```
<pages:PopupPage.Animation>

    <animations:MoveAnimation 
     PositionIn="Right"
     PositionOut="Right"
     DurationIn="300"
     DurationOut="300"
     EasingIn="SinOut"
     EasingOut="SinIn"
     HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>

 </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
```

Any solution with RG plugin?

Comment: Maybe, `Rg.plugins.popup` can do that. It should be noted that the writing format of the question needs attention, and you can share the picture of the desired effect, which will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It's not about the animation, that will only control the appearance. You should make sure the content of the popup page is properly arranged. For instance, here is the XAML for a popup page that will display a square popup in the top right corner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages:PopupPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="MyApp.Views.RandomPopupPage">
    <StackLayout
        BackgroundColor="White"
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        Margin="20"
        WidthRequest="100"
        HeightRequest="100"
        Spacing="0">
        <Label
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="Some text here" />
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

It has a StackLayout vertically aligned with start (TOP) and horizontally aligned with end (right). It also has a fixed width and height. You should arrange its elements as you do with a normal page keeping in mind it has a transparent background.

It looks like this: [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Alu4.png)

Answer (score 1):

> Tried to set a popup page that should appear on right.

From **Rg.plugins.popup** document , can [custom animations](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Animations#custom-animations) as follow:

Creat **UserAnimation** class

```
class UserAnimation : MoveAnimation
{
    private double _defaultTranslationY;

    public UserAnimation()
    {
        DurationIn = DurationOut = 300;
        EasingIn = Easing.SinOut;
        EasingOut = Easing.SinIn;
        PositionIn = MoveAnimationOptions.Right;
        PositionOut = MoveAnimationOptions.Right;
    }
    //1
    public override void Preparing(View content, PopupPage page)
    {
        base.Preparing(content, page);
        page.IsVisible = false;
        if (content == null) return;
        _defaultTranslationY = content.TranslationY;

    }

    //3
    public override void Disposing(View content, PopupPage page)
    {
        base.Disposing(content, page);
        page.IsVisible = true;
        if (content == null) return;
        content.TranslationY = _defaultTranslationY;

    }
    //2
    public async override Task Appearing(View content, PopupPage page)
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task>();
        taskList.Add(base.Appearing(content, page));
        if (content != null)
        {
            var topOffset = GetTopOffset(content, page);
            var leftOffset = GetLeftOffset(content, page);
            taskList.Add(content.TranslateTo(content.Width, _defaultTranslationY, DurationIn, EasingIn));
        };

        page.IsVisible = true;
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    }
    //4
    public async override Task Disappearing(View content, PopupPage page)
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task>();
        taskList.Add(base.Disappearing(content, page));
        if (content != null)
        {
            _defaultTranslationY = content.TranslationX - content.Width;

            var topOffset = GetTopOffset(content, page);
            var leftOffset = GetLeftOffset(content, page);

            taskList.Add(content.TranslateTo(leftOffset, _defaultTranslationY, DurationOut, EasingOut));
        };

        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    }
}
```

Use it in **Xaml**:

```
<pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <animations:UserAnimation/>
</pages:PopupPage.Animation>
```

Not sure if the effect below is what you want, but you can use this method to customize the animation.

[image]